# Avoid copying input data when calling Python functions using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, pybind11

I'm using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) to call [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) functions from my C++ code, namely to plot some `std::vector<double>`.

However, I noticed that the automatic conversion feature between C++ and Python types provided by `pybind11` always performs a copy of the underlying data when converting my `std::vector` into an equivalent Python data type before passing it to the `matplotlib` function. How can I avoid this copy?

An example code is the following:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <vector>

namespace py = pybind11;
py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
py::object plt = py::module::import("matplotlib.pyplot");
std::vector<double> x = ...;
std::vector<double> y = ...;
plt.attr("plot")(x, y); // This lines copies x and y
plt.attr("show")();
```

Since `x` and `y` may be very large, I would like to avoid copying them before passing them to Python. Is there a way to pass `x` and `y` by reference? Or could I replace the `std::vector` with some `pybind11` wrapper class onto native Python types?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, what you need to do is make the type opaque so that pybind11 won't try to convert it to a python type and then also tell pybind11 to automatically bind your vector type as something that exposes a python `list` style API.

You need to include the necessary header

```
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
```

and then before any code that uses it, declare that `std::vector<double>` is an opaque type.

```
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<double>);
```

And finally, you need to tell pybind11 how to bind that type into python. This is the tricky bit because it does require a target module for the bind. But luckily, you already have a module because you just imported one (and it is the target of your call as well).

So you can do

```
  auto plt = py::module::import("matplotlib.pyplot");
  py::bind_vector<std::vector<double>>(plt, "VectorDouble");
```

The final code block (which compiles and runs just fine on my system) is

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
#include <vector>


PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<double>);


namespace py = pybind11;


int main()
{
  py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
  std::vector<double> x {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::vector<double> y {4, 5, 6, 7};
  auto plt = py::module::import("matplotlib.pyplot");
  py::bind_vector<std::vector<double>>(plt, "VectorDouble");
  plt.attr("plot")(x, y);
  plt.attr("show")();
}
```

Advanced STL docs for pybind11 are here
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/cast/stl.html

In addition, the `test_embed\test_interpreter.cpp` and `test_stl_binders.cpp` test files in the pybind11 repo contain even more examples.

Comment: Is there a way to make non-STL types opaque? For example, objects of custom classes?